# HEROKU Free tier SSL: You need to be running on either Hobby or Professional dynos to be able to use SNI SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am hosting my website for free on heroku. So I have to enable SSL manually since their automated version is only available starting from the hobby dyno.
I've generated a certificate using:

> sudo certbot certonly --manual

When I tried to add the certificate:

> sudo heroku certs:add
> /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitename.com/fullchain.pem
> /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitename.com/privkey.pem

I got this error:

> ▸    You need to be running on either Hobby or Professional dynos to
> be able to use SNI SSL.

I thought doing this manually was possible but apparently even manually I need the hobby version.

Comment: Well I found this :"The SSL certificate and the endpoint itself are technically free. But Heroku does have a restriction that the app must use Hobby dynos ($7/dyno/mo) or professional dynos ($25-500/dyno/mo)

There's nothing that can be done about this. It's simply a restriction of the Heroku platform. That said, you'd be more than welcome to submit a PR to make this restriction clearer in the README.
Or lobby Heroku to make it available in the free tier, but I wouldn't like to guarantee how successful that would be."

Answer (score 0):

Just bypass Heroku's `cert` system altogether. I was able to secure my free level staging site by incorporating the `cert` file into the `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --timeout 90 --certfile /certs/fullchain.pem --keyfile /certs/privkey.pem --keep-alive 5 --log-level debug --log-file -
```

The methodology should be similar to `nginx` or `apache`. Just work it into your `Procfile`.

Comment: Can you elaborate and specify if you used a custom domain or a *.herokuapp.com? It is said (link below) that "You cannot "bypass Heroku's cert system" because certificate presentation and TLS termination happens before the request gets to your dyno(s).", and it is what I experienced. https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/vcazg1/really_no_way_to_have_https_on_free_dynos_fastapi/